# maximum number of classes for tensorflow object detector

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I want to add about 2000 classes in tensorflow object detector and want to train it for these many classes. Is there any constraint of network in supporting such a large number of classes ? If yes, what is the maximum number of classes a tensorflow object detector can support ?